# Making a bar graph with dummy column in Excel

Tags: excel, graph

I need to create a graph just like the one shown in the picture i attached. it does not need to have the curve, rectangular bars would be fine. but the axis should be the same. from what i searched, i found out i have to make dummy columns but I cant figure out how to make it in excel. If someone can explain, it will be helpful. Thanks (link to sample data in excel file is attached).

[Excel workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArYn8TW3_a3d3yY6tcsBpNwy40AF)

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSSpf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

1. sort the data in "Full load operating hours in 2015 [h/a]" from largest to smallest.
2. select ONLY the non-zero valued data and make a new 3 columns x 17 rows table. (paste at new, fresh sheet)
3. Add the column headers.
4. Select all data+headers > press F11 > Design > Chg Chart Type > Select:Surface .

That's the closest in Excel built function can do that I knew... Hope it helps.